# Is it possible to run RDP on Pi3 running Win 10 IoT?

Tags: pi-3, remote, windows-iot

Has anyone been successful in running some sort of Remote Desktop session from a PC to a RaspBerry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think IoT runs a desktop environment, there is nothing to RDP into. It's not even as bare as server core where you end up at a Powershell prompt. PS remoting or the web interface are the only management options.